# Need help with UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

I've been having some serious trouble figuring out how to unwrap this.

I have this game rip area by default: https://puu.sh/BIx5P/669958c5d1.png

I'm trying to get the horizontal stripe to go seamlessly around the entire mesh. The closest result I've achieved was with smart project: https://puu.sh/BIxbi/9344ed877a.png

Fixing the seams manually isn't really going to work for me as the UVS in the broken areas are kind of all over the place, flipped, and this is an ongoing concern.

Any way to just evenly have the texture go around everything? Flattening the mesh and then unflattening it didn't work out for me when I tried either as the textures started stretching badly in places. (tried with project from view perspective mode)

Comment: I guess you need to think about an intelligent way to mark your seams

Comment: I think you might not even need a seam at all, just a long horizontal surface.